# Generalizing on-policy distribution of states

Tags: mathematical-statistics, reinforcement-learning

The box on page 199 of [Reinforcement Learning: An Introduction, Second Edition](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xeUDVGWGUUv1-ccUMAZHJLej2C7aAFWY/view)
talks about distribution of states in on-policy episodic settings. I want to generalize it for continuing tasks as is asked to do in some of the exercises in chapter 13. It seems to be a simple fix of adding {\gamma} to the second term (as mentioned at the bottom of the box), however, I am unable to see how that discounts the fraction of states in long term.

Does someone have a more sound proof of this?

**EDIT:**
The question should be relevant for episodic discounted case rather than for continuing task.

Comment: I don't think the exercise asks to generalise $\mu(s)$ to continuous tasks, just to episodic discounted ones (REINFORCE only works on episodic problems anyway). Also, changing $\gamma$ cannot change the on-policy distribution for a given policy $\pi(a|s)$. Instead it alters how states are weighted when considering the objective $J(\theta)$

Comment: I was under the impression that episodic discounted cases will correspond to handling continuing task. I might be wrong. In any case, do you think that {\mu} will change after generalizing it to the episodic discounted case?

Comment: The distribution of states won't change. Whether it changes $\mu$ (by the way, use syntax `$\mu$` to get LaTeX rendering on site) depends on whether you consider that to be a correction factor for $J(\theta)$ (yes) or whether it represents the state distribution (no, so make the new factor due to $\gamma$ explicit in the formula for  $J(\theta)$)

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not got through all the maths on those pages, and not able to figure this out in enough detail for an answer. But I'm reasonably certain of my statements in the above comments.